# Auto refresh Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, google-chrome

How do I make Stack Overflow refresh periodically or update itself whenever a new question is asked?

I use Google Chrome and I searched for such an extension at the chrome web store but could not find one. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?hl=en&category=ext&q=stack+overflow

How easy is it, to write one, if such a thing doesn't exist?

Comment: I am sure it exists. Why don't you suggest this as a feature to Stackoverflow instead?

Comment: Perhaps something like [StackStalker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo?hl=en)?

Comment: This extension refreshes the timeline at twitter.com. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdpiilkeoldobfomlhipnnfanmgfllmp

I am looking for something equivalent on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would like this feature so that as I keep SO open in the browser for extended periods of time, I do not have to keep clicking my account name to refresh my inbox. An embedded solution on SO as opposed to a wrap-around programatic one is one I would vote up.

Answer (score 1):

To auto refresh a page, all you do is create a [Content Script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and do an `window.location.reload()` inside, just a single line. In your manifest, just add a pattern match to stackoverflow domain.

Just make sure you know by adding that, it will reload your page periodically, which will be a strange user experience. Now, if you want to update itself whenever a new question has been asked, that is somewhat a different issue. You would need to manage that in the background page and do periodic requests to Stack Overflow using [RSS](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/google-chrome-extension) or [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids). Once you figure out a new change occurred, just send a `chrome.tabs.update` call to the tab on the same URL.

Comment: You might also want to make sure you auto refresh only on the home page or the questions page. You don't want it to wander away when you're answering a question or something else

Answer (score 0):

You could just sign up for a RSS feed for the tags that you're interested in, then stick that in whatever feed reader you use (if you do). Either that, or sign up to one of the multiple Stack overflow twitter bots.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this feature just to refresh SO to visit it consecutive days during your holiday voyage? Or you need a feature to get informed about some new answers or questions?
If second, use [StackStalker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo?hl=en) or [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds)