# Is Auto-refresh against the spirit of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, review

Given how the front page and the review queues work (First Posts and Late Answers in particular), it almost begs a user to use an auto-refresh until an opportunity comes by. As an avid reviewer on Stack Overflow myself, I've thought about it. **Not to imply I have, if this activity turns out to be unacceptable...**

I have looked around to see if this common thing--well not so much, because I know it would be--more out of curiosity to see if people are openly talking about it.

It appears [they](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/refresh-on-the-frontpage) [are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94419/auto-refresh-stack-overflow), [and have requested features for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/refresh-on-the-frontpage) too, so I could guess it's not against the rules if folks aren't all over that saying **"No. don't do it."** But still, I haven't seen any question explicitly asking this, so here goes.

Now look. If I were to do this myself, I would do it in review queues because (yes, badges are nice, but) I sincerely want to contribute to the community. This way, I make sure I fit as many reviews as I'm allowed in whatever time I'm awake at the keyboard. I do not robo-review. Each time I would stop, read the post, probably edit or flag them (and I have **no** rejected flags yet out of some 80), vote...you know the works. I have never been banned from editing and I'm mystified as to how some do it. Reviewing things right comes easily to me. My argument with all this is, adding auto-refresh (every, say 5 seconds) to my existing review process would only make me a more productive reviewer and allow me to contribute more to the community.

On the other hand, these queues in particular remain empty for a reason. If I never reviewed again from these queues again, someone else would pick up the gauntlet and these queues still remain empty (this is a good thing). Then, in that case, I place undue strain on the servers.

If for nothing else, I guess it's the old RuneScape gamer in me, but I wonder, is auto-refreshing (particularly in review queues) against the spirit and vision of Stack Exchange?

**If you think so, consider this a little further:**

Let's say you have a way to refresh only until a review comes up. Even if you go away from the keyboard, eventually the refreshes will stop. Do you think that would be hurtful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't against the spirit and vision of Stack Exchange.

However, autorefresh directly impacts performance. The number of browser windows that will be autorefreshed is going to be higher (possibly much higher) than the number of those that actually need to be refreshed (that is, are being actively monitored by someone).

With the kind of scale we have, auto refresh will just hurt.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edit, sorry I didn't make it inb4 your answer. What do you think about that?

Comment: @Gutblender - I think you are underestimating how much a "little" thing like this could hurt performance. And I can tell you that the review queues have been a problem for us on that front for a while now.

Comment: Live refresh through web sockets is working well for questions for a long time now, why not add such a thing to review queues? Don't auto refresh, instead have a live connection that will push new items when they appear.

Comment: @ShadowWizard New questions/answers are shown to everyone (minus client-side filtering of ignored tags). Review queues are built for each user individually.

Comment: So can't the sockets connection access whatever code is being used to determine the review queue of each user?